# What does 楽しめてない mean?

Tags: meaning, potential-form

What does 楽しめてない mean?

Context: 私クリスマスたのしめてない。

I know that 楽しめる means "to be able to enjoy", and it's negative form is 楽しめない. Where did that 「て」come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammar aside, て is the て of te-form and adds progressive aspect for 楽しめる. So it means *not being able to enjoy*, which is practically synonymous to *I'm not enjoying*.

---

Grammatically, it is a form of 楽しめていない, where the first い is dropped. 楽しめている is the progressive form of 楽しむ, just like 読んでいる is of 読む (読んでる is likewise possible).

---

Happy Holidays:)